# MySQL date search doesn't work expectedly on datetime field if time is also included in the query

Tags: mysql

I am wondering why the following query doesn't yield any result if time is also included in the query?

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_posts` WHERE DATE(`post_date_published`) = '2013-05-05 16:20:58'
```

However, when time is excluded from the search parameter

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_posts` WHERE DATE(`post_date_published`) = '2013-05-05'
```

Then it fetches the related record from database.

[image]

How can we fetch record still using time in the query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compare a `DATE` with an expression that isn't also `DATE`, it treats the date as being at time `00:00:00`. This is mentioned in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/using-date.html):

> When you compare a DATE, TIME, DATETIME, or TIMESTAMP to a constant string with the <, <=, =, >=, >, or BETWEEN operators, MySQL normally converts the string to an internal long integer for faster comparison (and also for a bit more “relaxed” string checking).

So it's comparing the numeric representation of the date with the numeric representation of the datetime string constant, and they don't match because of the different times.

So you need to remove the time from the string:

```
SELECT * FROM `tb_posts` WHERE DATE(`post_date_published`) = DATE('2013-05-05 16:20:58')
```

Comment: That's what exactly I was thinking to do. Is this somewhere mentioned in any docs?

Comment: @Sachin This is not different from `FLOOR(float_value) = '2.34'` and `FLOOR(float_value) = FLOOR('2.34')`.

Comment: @Sachin I've added the documentation.

Comment: IMHO the first version has been more accurate. As I understand your answer now - `SELECT DATE('2013-05-05 16:20:58') = '2013-05-05 00:00:00'` should return 0/FALSE. But it returns 1/TRUE, as I would have expected.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read the documentation carefully enough. There's a previous paragraph that talks about comparing with a string constant, I've updated the answer to reference it.